# Hibernate mapping object to table having a certain value?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, orm, jakarta-ee

I have a table called `Object` that has a foreign key to `ObjectType` table.

For my domain model, I have an object for each `ObjectType`:  How do I map the domain object `Article` to the `Object` table where the `objectTypeFk` column maps to `ObjectType` row having the value `Article`.  I also have a domain object `ObjectType` which is simply an enum of all possible types (which I was hoping to tie into the mapping somehow).

I had no luck looking through the docs as I don't know what to search for (i.e. how to describe what I'm trying to achieve).

Comment: Are you using XML configuration? JPA with annotations?

Comment: Strictly XML configuration. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is possible without some hacks, but what you are describing sounds close to a inheritance strategy using "table per hierarchy", except that it would use "Article" as the discriminator (a simple varchar column) instead of a FK.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tableperclass